# How can I read this GE type I-55-S electric meter?

Tags: electrical, meter

[image: GE I-55-S]

Should I just round to the closest number on each dial?  Is the reading 3708 kWh?

Comment: Blast! You foiled my plan to hack the meter!  (Humor: it's an old mechanical meter.)

Comment: @Harper it's a paranoid habit of mine to censor all serial numbers no matter what :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reads 2698 -> read the number BEFORE each dial, remember that if one dial turns clockwise the next will turn counter-clockwise

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  No idea why this wasn't clear with a web search...